# Apache-poi: Auto resizing hides/truncates the decimal points of the value inside the cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have made a program that writes on excel sheet cells some numbers. In the end, after all values are written and the excel sheet is ready to be saved, just before that, I call the method `void autoSizeColumn(int column)` for every column on my sheet so I can auto-sized it.

The thing is when I write the value 12.7 for instance instead of getting the value of 12.7 as expected, I get the value 13 and the cell is not autosized like the others. When I resize the cell by my self using my mouse and make it bigger, the value becomes automatically 12.7.
My question is: how can I configure my program, so the value is not truncated to 13 or the cell using auto-size stays large enough, so the truncation wont happen.

originally I get this:

[image: originally I get this:]

But when I enlarge the cell manually I get this:

[image: But when I enlarge the cell manually I get this:]

Comment: have you tried forcing data format? ex:   `XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
     DataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat(); cellStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("###,#0"));`

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work. I think I have to find a way to disable the auto-truncation of excel.